# Modern treatment of $q$-differential operators/$\mathcal{D}_q$ modules?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

The basic idea of $q$-differential operators: replace
$$\partial\cdot x^n\ =\ nx^{n-1} \hspace{10mm}\rightsquigarrow\hspace{10mm} \partial\cdot x^n \ =\ [n]_q x^{n-1} $$
where $[n]_q=(q^{n}-1)/(q-1)$ is the quantum integer. This gives the algebras of differential operators $\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{A}^1)$ and $q$-differential operators $\mathcal{D}_q(\mathbf{A}^1)$ on the affine line.

---

A modern book on $\mathcal{D}$-modules will probably include (in a very loose order):

1. The definition of $\mathcal{D}\text{-Mod}$ for smooth schemes.
2. The four functors $f^* ,f_* ,\text{Hom},\otimes$.
3. Kashiwara's theorem and the definition of $\mathcal{D}\text{-Mod}$ for all schemes.
4. Holonomic $\mathcal{D}$-modules: the six functors, Verdier duality, Mayer Vietoris.
5. The Riemann-Hilbert correspondence and perverse sheaves.
6. Beilinson-Bernstein, lots of explicit computations for $G/B$ translating particular representation-theory constructions to $\mathcal{D}$-modules.
7. D modules as crystals, their definition for arbitrary prestacks.

---

**My question:** How much of this has been carried out for $\mathcal{D}_q$-modules? If the answer is "not much", is there at least an expectation about what part of 1-7+ should carry over, and what it should look like?

---

**Edit:** to respond to the comment below and show that this question isn't dead, I'll sketch how to define $\mathcal{D}_q$ for $X$ any smooth affine scheme with a $\mathbf{C}^\times$ action. First, $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is $\mathbf{Z}$-graded due to the action. Then define *$q$-derivation* to be an element $d$ of $\text{End}_\mathbf{C}(\mathcal{O}(X))$ satisfying
$$d(ab)\ =\ d(a)b+(q^{|a|}a) d(b)$$
for homogeneous elements $a,b\in \mathcal{O}(X)$. Then define $\mathcal{D}_q$ to be the algebra generated by $\mathcal{O}(X)$ and the $q$-derivations.

Comment: I think already 1 doesn't really make sense, so everything else shouldn't, too.

Comment: I was under the impression you could define a $q$-derivation on $\mathcal{O}_X$ (giving $\mathcal{D}_q$) for any smooth scheme $X$ with $\mathbf{G}_m$-action.

Comment: @WillSawin At least some version of 7 makes sense in the integral p-adic setting: there is a q-crystalline site in Bhatt–Scholze where one can talk about crystals, and it should be closely related to prismatic crystals.

Comment: For flag varieties you can look here https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407048